# Convert Array to JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How do I convert

`["ID:2","ID:3","ID:4"]`

to

```
[{
  "ID":2
},
{
  "ID":3
},
{
  "ID":4
}]
```

because this type of data i have to send to my webservice

Comment: Where/how do you create your Array `["ID:2","ID:3","ID:4"]`? Is this format of any use?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the array to JSON or are you asking how to convert the array of strings to an array of objects? Those are two distinct problems.

Comment: Try `["ID:2","ID:3","ID:4"].map(s => {let [key, val] = s.split(':'); return {[key]: +val}})`

Comment: You should really use jQuery. It's really great and does all things.

Comment: I'd like to see how jQuery makes this at all simpler than plain ol' javascript @xenteros ... `does all things` - including suck the life out of a webpage

Comment: @JaromandaX https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/340236

Comment: ahhh, you were being sarcastic (or ironic?) @xenteros - nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting an array with objects, you could split the strings and build a new object with the wanted property and the numerical value.

```js
var data = ["ID:2","ID:3","ID:4"],
    result = data.map(function (s) {
        var p = s.split(':'),
            t = {};
        t[p[0]] = +p[1];
        return t;
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newArrayOfObjs =arr.map((item)=> {
 var obj = {};
 var splitItems = item.split(':');
 obj[splitItems[0]] = splitItems[1];
 return obj;
}
```

You'll have to split the string on ':' and set the 0th element as key and 1st element as value.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var aryExample = ["ID:2","ID:3","ID:4"], aryNew = [];
for( var i in aryExample ) {
  aryNew.push({ID:Number(aryExample[i].split(":")[1])});
}
console.dir(aryNew);
```

That should do it.